# JS: Given a list of x, y coordinates find missing coordinates between 1,1 and largest given

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, coordinates

Say I have:

```
var coords = [
    [2, 2],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 2],
    [3, 4]
];

var missing = [];
```

Using vanilla javascript, how could I check `coords` for every missing x, y value beginning at  `[1, 1]` and ending at, say, 1 more than the largest value in `coords` (`[4, 5]`).

I have a jsFiddle of what I've come up with so far but I can only get back the values `[1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]`: http://jsfiddle.net/UWE5x/  I can see why I'm just not sure where to go from here.

I'm sure there's a much more efficient way than the route I'm currently on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
var coords = [
    [2, 2],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 2],
    [3, 4]
];

var max_x = -1, max_y = -1, x, y;
var missing = [];
coords_obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    x = coords[i][0];
    y = coords[i][1];
    if (x > max_x) max_x = x;
    if (y > max_y) max_y = y;
    if (!coords_obj[x])
        coords_obj[x] = {};
    coords_obj[x][y] = 1;
}

for (x = 1; x <= max_x + 1; x++) {
    for (y = 1; y <= max_y + 1; y++) {
        if (!coords_obj[x] || !coords_obj[x][y])
            missing.push([x, y]);
    }
}
```

This results in the following for `missing`:

```
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,1],[2,3],[2,5],[3,1],[3,3],[3,5],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **[Ramda functional programming library](https://github.com/Crosseye/ramda)**, we can do this fairly simply, as seen on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/UK6yc/)**:

```
var missing = reject((function() {
    var makeKey = function(pair) {return pair[0] + "," + pair[1];};
    var found = map(makeKey, coords);
    return function(pair) {
        return contains(makeKey(pair), found);
    };
})(), xprod(
    range(1, 2 + Math.max.apply(null, map(get('0'), coords))),
    range(1, 2 + Math.max.apply(null, map(get('1'), coords)))
));
```

Ramda is still under development.  If it had an `difference` operator similar to its `union` one, this would be simpler still.  A library like **[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)** would have similar tools to make this easy (including `difference`.)

---

### Update

I was unhappy with this solution, and with what it demonstrated as being missing from **[Ramda](https://github.com/Crosseye/ramda)**, so I made some additions to the library, and I think this makes for **[nicer code](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/UK6yc/4/)** now:

```
var pairEq = andFn(eqProps(0), eqProps(1));

var missing = differenceWith(pairEq, xprod(
    range(1, 2 + max(map(get('0'), coords))),
    range(1, 2 + max(map(get('1'), coords)))
), coords);
```

I know this is probably not important to the OP, but it crystallized the need for several functions that I knew I wanted but hadn't gotten around to and one that I hadn't even considered but came out of doing this problem (although I didn't in the end use that one in the final version.)

Ramda now has `max`, `min`, `maxWith`, `minWith`, `eqProp`, `intersection`, `intersectionWith`, `difference`, `differenceWith`, `allPredicates`, and `anyPredicates` functions.  And this solution takes advantage of `max`, `eqProp`, `differenceWith`, but uses the already existing `andFn` instead of `allPredicates`.  Amazing how much change one minor little problem can drive!

Comment: Updated the jsFiddle to work with the latest Ramda library (andFn was removed)
http://jsfiddle.net/Semmel/L5u50wnf/

Comment: Thank you.  I've since realized that I should never post such things against the HEAD of the library, only against an existing branch.  Good catch!